# Using Ruby and Mechanize to make new Olympic medals count

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to remake the Olympic medals count on London2012 to better reflect the value of the medals.  Currently it is only sorted by gold medals.  I'd like to relist it by points, so gold=4, silver=2 and bronze=1 to make a new more rational list.  I probably want to remember the previous rank then add a new rank column as well.

I'd like to try mechanize to get raw data from site, then parse the data into rows and cols, apply the new counts, then remake the list.

From source at http://www.london2012.com/medals/medal-count/ each country has a block with medals like so:

```
<span class="countryName">Canada</span></a></div></div></td><td class="gold c">0</td><td class="silver c">2</td><td class="bronze c">5</td>
```

If I use agent.get('http://www.london2012.com/medals/medal-count') It shows the whole list.  How to parse specific spans and table data?

I also need to remember the rank, then when I make the new page put the new rank beside it.

Any tips on mechanize parsing and remembering data would be really helpful.  More importantly your thinking process in doing something like this, I'd appreciate the help to get me started.  This doesn't have to be a code answer

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to identify the table. In chrome load the page and right click anywhere on the table. Go to inspect element. Go up the heirarchy until you're on the table. Now select it and you'll see it looks like this:

```
<table class="or-tbl overall_medals sortable" summary="Schedule">
```

The overall_medals class looks like it will be unique so that's a good one to use. Now start irb and do:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get 'http://www.london2012.com/medals/medal-count/'
```

double check that the table is unique:

```
page.search('table.overall_medals').size 
#=> 1 (good, it is)
```

You can get all the data from the table into an array with:

```
page.search('table.overall_medals tr').map{|tr| tr.search('td').map(&:text)}
```

Notice that the first 2 rows are empty, let's get rid of them by using a range:

```
data = page.search('table.overall_medals tr')[2..-1].map{|tr| tr.search('td').map(&:text)}
```

The second row isn't really empty, it has the column names (in th's instead of td's). You can get those with:

```
columns = page.search('table.overall_medals tr[2] th').map{|th| th.text.strip}
```

You can get these into hashes with:

```
rows = data.map{|row| Hash[columns.zip row]}
```

Now you can do

```
rows[0]['Country']
#=> "United States of America"
```

Or even one big hash:

```
countries = rows.map{|row| {row['Country'] => row}}.reduce &:merge
```

now:

```
countries['France']['Gold']
#=> "8"
```

Comment: wow..  what do the &:text and &:merge items do?  The 4th code block from the top is mapping a map of a search so I was wondering if you could put into words what that's doing.  Next from 2 to -1, I think that's to the beginning so I'm okay there.

Comment: rows = data.map{|row| Hash[columns.zip row]} can you explain the zip here?

Comment: map(&:text ) is a shortcut for map{|x| x.text}, same for &:merge. columns.zip(row) will line up the columns with row like so: [[column[0], row[0]], [column[1], row[1]], etc] so it can be easily put into a hash

Comment: Ah ha!  Thank you so much and for taking the time.  Have a nice weekend ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might find this Medals API useful (Assuming your question is not specifically about Mechanize)

http://apify.heroku.com/resources/5014626da8cdbb0002000006

It uses Nokogiri to parse the site and the output is available as JSON:

http://apify.heroku.com/api/olympics2012_medals.json